# what is the meaning of a(b) in matlab ? where a and b are matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose:

```
a =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 2     3     4
```

and

```
b =

 1     3     2
 6     4     8
```

In MATLAB`a(b)` gives:

```
>> a(b)

ans =

 1     2     4
 3     2     6
```

What is the reason for this output?

Answer (score 1):

when you have a matrix a:

```
a =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

and b:

```
b =
     1     3     4
     3     2     6
```

then a(b) is a way of adressing items in a and gives you:

```
>> a(b)
ans =
     1     7     2   
     7     4     8
```

to understand this you have to think of a als a single column vector

```
>> a(:)
ans =
     1
     4
     7
     2
     5
     8
     3
     6
     9
```

now the first row of `b` (1 3 4) addresses elements in this vector so the first, the 3rd and the forth element of that single column vector which are `1` `7` and `2` are adressed. Next the secound row of `b` is used as adresses for a secound line in the output so the 3rd, the 2nd and the 6th elements are taken from `a`, those are 7 4 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a kind of [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).
Matrix indexes numeration in 'a' matrix is:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate to this post where I gave an answer: [Got confused with a vector indexed by a matrix, in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997632/got-confused-with-a-vector-indexed-by-a-matrix-in-matlab/)

However, I would like to duplicate my answer here as I think it is informative.

---

That's a very standard MATLAB operation that you're doing.  When you have a vector or a matrix, you can provide another vector or matrix in order to access specific values.  Accessing values in MATLAB is not just limited to single indices (i.e. `A(1), A(2)` and so on).

For example, let's say we had a vector `a = [1 2 3 4]`.  Let's also say we had `b` as a matrix such that it was `b = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]`.  By doing `a(b)` to access the vector, what you are essentially doing is a lookup.  The output is basically the same size as `b`, and you are creating a matrix where there are 3 rows, and each element accesses the first, second and third element.  Not only can you do this for a vector, but you can do this for a matrix as well.

Bear in mind that when you're doing this for a matrix, you access the elements in **column major format**.  For example, supposing we had this matrix:

```
 A = [1 2
      3 4
      5 6
      7 8]
```

`A(1)` would be 1, `A(2)` would be 3, `A(3)` would be 5 and so on.  You would start with the first column, and increasing indices will traverse down the first column.  Once you hit the 5th index, it skips over to the next column.  So `A(5)` would be 2, `A(6)` would be 4 and so on.

Here are some examples to further your understanding.  Let's define a matrix `A` such that:

```
 A = [5 1 3
      7 8 0
      4 6 2]
```

Here is some MATLAB code to strengthen your understanding for this kind of indexing:

```
 A = [5 1 3; 7 8 0; 4 6 2]; % 3 x 3 matrix
 B = [1 2 3 4];
 C = A(B); % C should give [5 7 4 1]
 D = [5 6 7; 1 2 3; 4 5 6];
 E = A(D); % E should give [8 6 3; 5 7 4; 1 8 6]
 F = [9 8; 7 6; 1 2];
 G = A(F); % G should give [2 0; 3 6; 5 7]
```

As such, the output when you access elements this way is whatever the size of the vector or matrix that you specify as the argument.

In order to be complete, let's do this for a vector:

```
 V = [-1 9 7 3 0 5]; % A 6 x 1 vector
 B = [1 2 3 4];
 C = V(B); % C should give [-1 9 7 3]
 D = [1 3 5 2];
 E = V(D); % E should give [-1 7 0 9]
 F = [1 2; 4 5; 6 3];
 G = V(F); % G should give [-1 9; 3 0; 5 7]
```

**NB:** You have to make sure that you are not providing indexes that would make the accessing out of bounds.  For example if you tried to specify the index of 5 in your example, it would give you an error.  Also, if you tried anything bigger than 9 in my example, it would also give you an error.  There are 9 elements in that 3 x 3 matrix, so specifying a column major index of anything bigger than 9 will give you an out of bounds error.